# jQuery .load() with input selector by name

Tags: javascript, jquery

so i have a form on one page with hidden input field:

> input id="test" name="categoryname" type="hidden" value="Health"

---

I want to use the load function, but i cannot get that categoryname selected in any way.

> $( "#result" ).load( "domain.com/test.html **[name='categoryname']**"
>   );

I know that i can use id selector like #test, but that is not an option, since i have forms with different types of hidden fields across the whole website and it will take a lot of time to update them.

My only option is to select by name, but the above doesn't work.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: `[name='categoryname']` is the selector you need but you'll have to construct a jQuery object, eg: `$("[name='categoryname']")` and then you can get this input's value `$("[name='categoryname']").val()`

Comment: Why do you have to use load()?

Comment: Why do you have to use load()?
 - Because i want to get the value, but i am doing this on a different page than the /test.html.

@Titus:

Thank you, but the goal pretty much is to get the val from a different page than the current one. That's why i want to pass the DOM and get the value by selector for input name. Unfortunately, what you have suggested works only for the current page IMO. Let me know...

Full code will be:

$('<div />').load("domain.com/test.html [name='categoryname']", function(data) {
 alert($(this).find("[name='categoryname']").html());

Comment: You cannot use `.load` to extract part of the response, you'll have get the entire response, create a `document` from it and then extract the data that you're interested in, you should take a look at [`jQuery.parseHTML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the `categoryname` as follows:

```js
var categoryname = $("input[name=categoryname]").val();

$( "#result" ).load( "domain.com/test.html" + categoryname );
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, why you are loading files like:

```
$( "#result" ).load("domain.com/test.html[name='categoryname']");
```

Which cause 404 errors:

```
$( "#result" ).load("domain.com/test.htmlHealth");
```

I think you want to load files like:

```
var val = $('input[name="categoryname"]').val();

$( "#result" ).load(`domain.com/test.html?${encodeURI(val)}`);
//Or 
$( "#result" ).load(`domain.com/test.html?name=${encodeURI(val)}`);
//Or
$( "#result" ).load(`domain.com/${encodeURI(val)}.html`);
```